# Get the size (after it has been "stretched") of an item in a ViewBox

Tags: wpf, size, viewbox, actualwidth

Consider the following:

Let's say the Window is 1024x768 and the ViewBox fills the entire window,
this means the TextBox is really large on the screen.

I want to get the size of the TextBox as it is currently on the screen.
If I get DesiredSize or ActualSize or even RenderedSize I always get 100.

Any suggestions?

**Update:** I could probably get the `ActualWidth` of the ViewBox and divide it by the `ActualWidth` of it's child which would give me the current scale factor and expose that as a property somehow but I'm not sure that's the best way to do it.

Comment: Have you considered checking the "Width" and "Height" properties of the TextBox?

Comment: @JasonMc92 - That would really won't help, as Width & Height would be most probably null. Width and Height are used to *request* sizes, not to ask for the actual size.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This is how you get the `ScaleTransform` the `ViewBox` exerts on its children:

```
var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(viewBox, 0) as ContainerVisual;
var scale = child.Transform as ScaleTransform;
```

Here `viewBox` is the ViewBox that textbox sits in.
Then you can just multiply `scale.ScaleX * textBox.ActualWidth` and you get the size in Screen coordinates

But it gets even easier!  To get that textbox's size directly in Screen Coordinates you do:

```
textbox.PointToScreen(new Point(textbox.ActualWidth,textbox.ActualHeight)) - textbox.PointToScreen(new Point(0,0))
```