# How to get a WPF Viewbox coefficient of scaling applied

Tags: wpf, silverlight, layout, viewbox

In case we use WPF (Silverlight) `Viewbox` with `Stretch="UniformToFill"` or `Stretch="Uniform"` when it preserves content's native aspect ratio, **how could we get knowing the current coefficient of scaling which were applied to the content?**

Note: we not always know the exact initial dimensions of the content (for example it's a Grid with lots of stuff in it).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

See this question: [Get the size (after it has been "streched") of an item in a ViewBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2119723/get-the-size-after-it-has-been-streched-of-an-item-in-a-viewbox)

Basically, if you have a `Viewbox` called viewbox, you can get the `ScaleTransform` like this

```
ContainerVisual child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(viewbox, 0) as ContainerVisual;
ScaleTransform scale = child.Transform as ScaleTransform;
```

You could also make an extension method for `Viewbox` which you can call like this

```
viewbox.GetScaleFactor();
```

**ViewBoxExtensions**

```
public static class ViewBoxExtensions
{
    public static double GetScaleFactor(this Viewbox viewbox)
    {
        if (viewbox.Child == null ||
            (viewbox.Child is FrameworkElement) == false)
        {
            return double.NaN;
        }
        FrameworkElement child = viewbox.Child as FrameworkElement;
        return viewbox.ActualWidth / child.ActualWidth;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a quick note to other Silverlight users - even though the question asks about the "WPF (Silverlight)" ViewBox, the solution doesn't work as is for Silverlight as it has no ContainerVisual class.