# Exempt control in AdornerLayer from ViewBox stretching

Tags: .net, wpf, c#-4.0

I have a WPF control that is roughly layed out like this:

```
<ViewBox Stretch="Uniform" Name="viewboxName">
    <ItemsControl>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <!-- a bunch of controls here that I want stretched in the viewbox -->
             </DataTemplate>
         </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</ViewBox>
```

Then, in the AdornerLayer, I have (using a technique based on http://shevaspace.blogspot.com/2007/02/visual-level-programming-vs-logical.html) a button control defined as

```
<Button>
    <Image Source="/AcchImageLoad;component/icons/metroStudio/ImageRotation.png" Stretch="None" />
</Button>
```

How can I get this button in the AdornerLayer to use the image's native resolution, instead of stretching with the ViewBox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, the idea is to get the transform from the `ViewBox` and apply the inverse, with a binding converter.

The binding converter can get the inverse with the following code:

```
((ContainerVisual)VisualTreeHelper
.GetChild((System.Windows.DependencyObject)viewbox, 0)).Transform.Inverse
```

In xaml, the binding would look something like

```
<Button.LayoutTransform>
    <MultiBinding Converter="{bc:ExemptFromViewboxTransformConverter}">
       <Binding Source="{x:Reference Name=viewboxName}" />
       <!-- The ActualWidth/ActualHeight bindings are only used to ensure 
            the transform updates when the window is resized. -->
        <Binding Source="{x:Reference Name=viewboxName}" Path="ActualWidth" />
        <Binding Source="{x:Reference Name=viewboxName}" Path="ActualHeight" />
    </MultiBinding>
</Button.LayoutTransform>
```

See also:

- [How to get a WPF Viewbox coefficient of scaling applied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5423334/how-to-get-a-wpf-viewbox-coefficient-of-scaling-applied)
- [Get the size (after it has been "streched") of an item in a ViewBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2119723/get-the-size-after-it-has-been-streched-of-an-item-in-a-viewbox)

Answer (score 0):

You can disable viewbox scaling using this solution: [Disable Viewbox Resize for Specific Elements](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/1109799/disable-viewbox-resize-for-specific-elements)

Basically, add a handler for ViewBox_SizeChanged and set the exempt element's transform to the inverse of the ViewBox's transform.

Then in your XAML, add ViewBoxExtra.DisableScaling="true", e.g.

```
<Rectangle Width="50" Height="50" local:ViewBoxExtra.DisableScaling="true"/>
```