# Get a Transform out of a Viewbox applied Scale Factor

Tags: wpf, transform, scale, viewbox

When I in WPF use a Viewbox, is it possible to get the factors which the Viewbox uses for scaling it's content? Or maybe get a Scaletransform which behaves the same way?

Like when you using a Path and set it's Stretch Property, you can get the Transform which is used from the RenderedGeometry.Transform Property. Is something like this with the Viewbox also possible?

Comment: How about dividing the Viewbox's ActualWidth or ActualHeight by the ActualWidth or ActualHeight of its child?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get the size (after it has been "stretched") of an item in a ViewBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2119723/get-the-size-after-it-has-been-stretched-of-an-item-in-a-viewbox)